# How to set the minzoom in openlayers to zero (0)

Tags: zooming, openlayers, openstreetmap

I created my first map with openlayers using this tutorial: https://github.com/openlayers/ol-vite

I know Leaflet and I know that zooming to 0-level is possible by default. Depending on the display area, it looks like in the picture.
[image]

I want to be able to zoom from 0 to 20 in openlayers.

This is my code in openlayers:

```
import './style.css';
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

Zooming only works down to zoom 2 or 3.

How do I achieve it in openlayers that zooms to zoom 0?

I have explicitly set minzoom to 0 (`minZoom: 0`). But even then it does not zoom to zoomlevel 0.

Comment: You need to specify `multiWorld: true` in the view options to override the single world constraint.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the option I need to find.